# Solve the that that that rebus

Tags: knowledge, rebus

It's a hard rebus to do and the rebus is: 3 "that"s

```
                                                                               that  
                                                                               that  
                                                                               that
```

Comment: Probably the author has a stutter.

Comment: It's a list of things Meat Loaf won't do for love.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is...

> "That's all right."

Comment: This is actually the correct answer, as the OP confirmed in a comment yesterday on the other answer :-)

Comment: My answer includes "all" (since the three are all to the right) which is a bit different, but I see your point. I didn't realize OP had accepted an answer since there was no green check mark,

Comment: Yep, I upvoted your answer, and hope it would be accepted if the OP returns.

Answer (score 2):

I thought there was a phrase

> It’s all that

but couldn’t find a link at short notice. I did find the following show, though:

> [All That](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_That)

And now that we’ve come to the end of this answer,

> That’s all, folks.

PS: from the horse’s mouth,

> That’s right!

Comment: Sorry its thats right

Comment: @user60673 Apologies, I don't understand that comment.

Comment: I believe the OP is telling you the answer to the rebus!

Comment: @GordonK Oh! Got it now, thanks :) ! But isn't the original *that-that-that* text in the middle of a horizontal scroll-box? When I scroll all the way to the right, the block of text appears to move to the left.

Comment: Since OP unfortunately decided to give up the answer in a comment, and it isn't actually in this answer, perhaps you could edit your answer to provide the intended solution.

Comment: @Rubio Done. :)

Comment: @Lawrence Now someone else found the answer, without seeing the OP's comment :-)